# Angular - Parse timestamp to date return syntax error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to check if a variable is null or not. If it isn't null, take the timestamp and parse date like this:

```
 {{user.lastLogin!=null ? user.lastLogin | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' : '-'}}
```

But the code throws an error:

> Parser Error: Conditional expression user.lastLogin!=null ? user.lastLogin | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' : '-' requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [{{user.lastLogin!=null ? user.lastLogin

Obviously it is a syntax error, but I don't know the correct way to do this.

What is the correct way to check variable and then (if it exists) parse to format date?

Comment: use safe operator https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to wrap the condition and date pipe with ()

> requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression

```
 {{ (user.lastLogin!=null) ? (user.lastLogin | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') : '-'}}
```

Comment: you can use the "safe operator" to save up a comparision: `{{user?.lastLogin?(user.lastLogin | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'):'-'}}`

Answer (score 1):

I would break this check into the DOM, like so:

```
<p *ngIf="user.lastLogin; else dash">{{ user.lastLogin | date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' }}</p>
<ng-template #dash><p>-</p></ng-template>
```